# Application layout shrinking in multiview mode

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]I have an android application and when I open it in my phone in multiview mode see capture attached the layout shrinks. How can I make it to stay the same and scroll it as needed like the google play store layout in the bottom in the capture attached.

[layoutImage] https://drive.google.com/file/d/13tfmB3BO4cLgYK6ZxKb5Cyyr8Cl3SwQa/view?usp=sharing

Below is my layout.xml file code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/separator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextDomain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hintURL"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.168" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPhone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hintPhone"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="phone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.297" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hintPassword"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.425" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switchTracking"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:text="@string/switchOff"
        android:textColorLink="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:theme="@style/SwitchTheme"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.57" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        style="@style/Divider"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.75"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.451"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.811"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewLongitude"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/lngSearching"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.25"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.928"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewLatitude"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/latSearching"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.241"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.88"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonExit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/exit"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.659" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any help on this please?

Thanks.

Comment: As much as possible do not use `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias` on each of your views. Just place it on your first item and "anchor" your next views to the top view.

Comment: Could you suggest some changes to my layout please?

Comment: Try the answer provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this layout. I removed the `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias`. You can just adjust the top margins of each view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                             android:id="@+id/separator"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                             tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextDomain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/hintURL"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="text"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"/>

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextPhone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/hintPhone"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="phone"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextDomain"/>

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextPass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/hintPassword"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextPhone"/>

    <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switchTracking"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/switchOff"
            android:textColorLink="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:theme="@style/SwitchTheme"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="64dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextPass"/>

    <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            style="@style/Divider"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.75"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewInfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.451"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.811"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewLongitude"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="@string/lngSearching"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.25"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.928"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewLatitude"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="@string/latSearching"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.241"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.88"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonExit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/exit"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/switchTracking"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```